# Asterisk confbridge, timeout only while waiting marked

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip

I have just configured an asterisk server for my home doorbell.
The goal is to allow my doorbell to join a conference room but wait for the first user to also join in order to start talking.

I managed to get it working with the following configuration:

**confbridge.conf**

```
[admin_user]
type=user
marked=yes
admin=yes
music_on_hold_when_empty=yes
quiet=yes

[default_user]
type=user
wait_marked=yes
end_marked=yes
music_on_hold_when_empty=yes
quiet=yes

[myconferenceroom]
type=bridge
max_members=10
```

**extensions.conf**

```
; for the doorbell
exten => 777,1,Progress()
exten => 777,2,Wait(1)
exten => 777,3,ConfBridge(1,myconferenceroom,default_user)

; for the other user
exten => 888,1,Progress()
exten => 888,2,Wait(1)
exten => 888,3,ConfBridge(1,myconferenceroom,admin_user)
```

The problem is that if no one is available to answer to the doorbell, the doorbell will stay in the conference forever.

I tried adding the "timeout" value to the default_user block, but it will kick out the doorbell also if someone answered the call.
I need some kind of timeout that is applied only while the doorbell is waiting for a marked user to join.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```
exten => 777,3,Set(TIMEOUT(absolute)=120)
```

Comment: Please explain why/how this works for future visitors

Comment: Why? Because it is TIMEOUT! absolute.